# How to create custom search form function including post "tags"

Tags: posts, customization, ajax, search

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="keyword" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Search video...">
<button id="search-keyword">Search</button>
```

When I click the "Search" button start a script like this:

```
if($('.current').hasClass('search-select')){
    action = 'my_create_posts_search'; //php function to do 
    ab = document.getElementsByClassName('keyword')[0].value; //get the value of input
}
```

Then an Ajax function starts:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_params.ajax_url, //wordpress ajax
    data: {
     'action': action, //php function to do  
     'ab': ab, //value of input
},
```

Then the action start and the code excecuted is this:

```
function my_create_posts_search($name) {
 //Pagination for posts
 $response = '';
 $paged = (int) (!is_null($_POST['clicked_times'])) ? $_POST['clicked_times'] : 0;

 $postsPerPage = 18;
 $postOffset = $paged * $postsPerPage;

 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => $postsPerPage, //pagination
    'offset'          => $postOffset, //pagination
    'category'        => 42, //post category
    's'               => $name, //value of input
    'orderby'         => 'date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
 );
 ... other things...
}
```

Everything works perfectly expcet when I would like to search by Post Tags.

How can I implement this feature?

I hope my code will help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WP_Query you can search for tags using this code:

`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'cooking' ) );`

For more tag options see this page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters